# Cannot remove JAR from cache

Tags: java, jar, applet, java-web-start

I have created a new JAR but I cannot see my changes made.  It seems like its caching the old JAR.

When I do a javaws -viewer  I see the date modified column for that JAR as April 7, which is old.  Is there another way to remove java JARS from  cache?

I know it works on my local machine with same JARS.  And the date modified field is May 23.  I'm testing on a TEST server where this problem is occurring.

Any ideas why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
javaws -uninstall
```

Comment: So this will remove java from the machine?

Comment: Nope Applet still being cached.  Any other way to remove it from cache?

Comment: Ok problem was that it was getting the applet from a different environment that was never updated.